# Reference to Albert Shanker (?) in "Sleeper"

Tags: woody-allen, sleeper-1973

In Sleeper (1973) there appears to be a reference to "Albert Shanker" who is identified as the person who devastates the world by starting World War III apparently by obtaining and detonating a nuclear weapon.

Is this is a reference to the educator Albert Shanker? What's the point of the joke?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it appears to be a reference to Albert Shanker, the educator, *union organizer and activist*.

As head of the United Federation of Teachers, he led union activities that included a nearly two-month-long teacher's strike that shut down almost all of the schools in New York, in 1968 ([New York City Teachers's Strike of 1968](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City_teachers%27_strike_of_1968)).

The strike was a particularly explosive issue, because it was related to issues of race (tensions between Jewish teachers and black parents and administrators).

Still, teachers union organizing is a far cry from nuclear assault, which is the source of the comedy.